# FS2 Running streams in sequence

Tags: scala, scala-cats, scalaz-stream, http4s, fs2

I have a fairly simple use case. I have two web service calls one fetches products and another fetches relationship. I want to run fetchProducts() first extract a field from the set of products and then pass the output to fetchRelationships(ids: Seq[String]) so that I can then set the relationship back on the product. Here's the code:

```
def fetchProducts(): Stream[IO, Seq[Product]]= {
 //webservice call
}

def fetchRelationship(ids: Seq[Product]): Stream[IO, Seq[Relationship]] = {
 //webservice call
}

//Pseudocode. How can I do this with fs2 Streams?
def process = {
      val prods = fetchProducts() //run this first
      val prodIds = prods.flatMap(i => i.productId)
      val rels = fetchRelationships(prodIds) //run after all all products are fetched 
      prods.forEach(p => p.setRelation(rels.get(p.id))
    }
}

 case class Product(productId: Option[String],
                        name: Option[String],
                        description: Option[String],
                        brandName: Option[String])
```

I am constrained by the external Api to get the results in batches. So I'm not sure how to express this using fs2 or if I should be using it at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you code in the question doesn't match your text description and misses quite a few important bits (such as whole `Relationship` class). Also it is not clear what

> I am constrained by the external Api to get the results in batches

really means. Also it is not clear why all fields in `Product` including `productId` are `Option`.

The following code compiles and might or might not be what you need:

```
case class Product(productId: Option[String],
                   name: Option[String],
                   description: Option[String],
                   brandName: Option[String],
                   relationships: mutable.ListBuffer[Relationship]) {

}

case class Relationship(productId: String, someInfo: String)

def fetchProducts(): Stream[IO, Seq[Product]] = {
  //webservice call
  ???
}

//    def fetchRelationships(ids: Seq[Product]): Stream[IO, Seq[Relationship]] = {
def fetchRelationships(ids: Seq[String]): Stream[IO, Seq[Relationship]] = {
  //webservice call
  ???
}

def process():  = {
  val prods = fetchProducts() //run this first
  val prodsAndRels: Stream[IO, (Seq[Product], Seq[Relationship])] = prods.flatMap(ps => fetchRelationships(ps.map(p => p.productId.get)).map(rs => (ps, rs)))

  val prodsWithFilledRels: Stream[IO, immutable.Seq[Product]] = prodsAndRels.map({ case (ps, rs) => {
    val productsMap = ps.map(p => (p.productId.get, p)).toMap
    rs.foreach(rel => productsMap(rel.productId).relationships += rel)
    ps.toList
  }
  })
  prodsWithFilledRels
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for the incomplete code. I figure I smart dev such as yourself would be able to figure it out :)

Comment: @JoseH.Martinez, from your comment I'm not sure if my answer is what you wanted or do you need something else?

Comment: You answered my question precisely @SergGr. Regarding the batching, I was wondering if there's a way to force processing the response as a stream of Product and Relationship object respectively. Since the complete payload as Json. But I guess that should be a separate question.

Comment: @JoseH.Martinez, if some answer is what you were looking for, you should mark that answer as accepted. As for batching I'm not sure I understand what you mean by this description. Probably separate question with more detailed description is the right way.

Comment: Hi @SergGr. I was wondering if there's a more idiomatic way to implement the algorithm, perhaps using fs2 Pipes.